# SharePoint Designer 2010 Custom Workflow does not start in subsite

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a subsite (http://testportal/documentcenter). When I add `Aproval - SharePoint 2010` workflow to document library where is in subsite, It works fine. 
But,  I open subsite with SharePoint Designer 2010 and `Copy & Modify` to `Aproval - SharePoint 2010` workflow, then I publish it. And I try add it to document library, I am typing someone's name to approvers field. When I click save button, I am getting this error message:

`The form cannot be submitted because of an error.`
(http://s7.postimage.org/b6rh9bc2z/Untitled.jpg)
[image: error]

If I leave blank approvers field, I can save it. But, When I start it manually, I am getting same error again.
How I can solve this problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Old post but if you not fixed yet, remove the Approvers & CC fields from Initiation Form Parameters and create new ones. Will work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Old post and you've probably solved this but check if you have Windows Update KB2553322 installed. Uninstall it and recreate your workflow and it should be ok :)

Comment: and what if we DO NOT have that windows update installed, then what's the answer??